# Windows 7 network identification is slow with linksys switch

Tags: windows-7, networking

I have a small network with a Linksys SRW224P switch, some windows 7 client machines and a Netgear FVX538 Prosafe VPN Firewall.

Now when i plug in a network cable into one of the windows 7 machine it takes over 30 seconds for it to perform network identification when connected to the switch.

If however i plug the same pc it into the Netgear product it is virtually instantaneous to identify the network.

The PC has a hard coded IP address along with gateway and DNS settings.

The firmware version of the switch is 2.0.1.4. Hardware version R01.

What could be causing this?  I'm no 'switch expert' but the switch is pretty much as it was delivered.

Any help / pointers gratefully received

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appeared to be the switch and options related for monitoring / restricting certain type of traffic.  I turned off all the options related to these and the network identification is very quick.